# PhpStorm inspect tool giving inconsistent results (different number of errors/warnings on sequential runs)

Tags: php, phpstorm, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, code-inspection

Trying to use PhpStorm inspect to tell a story of our code quality and track improvements.  It's working well and I have a script that daily pulls from git, runs the inspection and graphs everything.  Yay.

Here's the key line that runs the inspection:

```
command = "phpstorm.bat inspect " + reponame + " " + reponame + "\.idea\workspace.xml results\ -v2 -d " + pathtosrc
```

However, I've noticed that the numbers given aren't always consistent.

E.g. today, I ran it three times in a row on the same code repo, without any pulls, code changes or anything, and got different results.

```
Type         Run 1, Run 2, Run 3
ERROR        531,   531,   530
WARNING      12895, 12893, 12878
WEAK WARNING 18425, 18425, 18424
INFORMATION  152,   152,   152
TYPO         82,    82,    82
```

I can't fathom a reason for this, but if there is one and I can fix it, I'd like to know.  I would have thought running the same tool on the same code would always produce the same result, no?

Comment: And what if you run Inspect Code from the IDE interactively several times in a row, will it show the same results?

Comment: @duck_in_hat interesting, I nearly discarded that as the IDE I have scopes set, which aren't as usable on the command line. But I checked anyway. Inconsistent there too!
    Type         Run 1, Run 2, Run 3
    ERROR          654,   529,   528
    WARNING      12772, 12302, 12510
    WEAK WARNING 15834, 15676, 15984
    TYPO         33,    30,    30

Comment: Can you limit inspection to a single file, and somehow print out what errors were found? If you understand what errors are inconsistently shown, you might find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to invalidate caches `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` before inspection

Comment: sadly no, tried that three times in a row, 3 different results (in the IDE).    And I'm talking wildly different results - >5% in cases.

Comment: Could you update the question and add the command which you run to inspect code

Comment: Added.  Although it does the same in the IDE, so not sure it's the command line issue :/

(in IDE I go Code->Inspect Code)